# Como Agrego Función No conecta con MySQL en PhP

Tags: php, mysqli

¿Como le digo a la Web que mi base de mi hosting conecta o no conecta?

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Admin", "almacen");
// aqui como le digo a la web si esta conectada o no?
?>
```

Comment: No te entiendo, quieres decir como puedes consultar si tras el `mysqli_connect`, estás (o no) realmente conectado a la BBDD?

Answer (score 2):

Esto es para saber si se ha conectado satisfactoriamente a la base de datos:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error al conectarse a la BD " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar el siguiente código para conectarte a la base

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Admin", "almacen");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }else{ echo "Conexión exitosa";
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Eliobeth. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Podrías agregar una pequeña descripción explicando cómo esto resuelve el problema de la pregunta?